# regex for physical memory in HPUXPARISC

Tags: java, regex

The input

```
grep "Physical" /var/adm/syslog/syslog.log
```

The output

```
 May  4 21:07:00 getz vmunix:     Physical: 6289408 Kbytes, lockable: 4604660 Kbytes, available: 5417880 Kbytes
```

or from below get me `6289408`

```
May  4 21:07:00 getz vmunix:     Physical: 6289408 Kbytes
```

I want the value of `Physical:` only the numbers, how can i do that in simple regex i am using java(but i just need the regex here)?

**Note**: You can **test the regex** for me [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

**Update**

Let me make the question more clear.

1. I have my java code in place, i am writing plugins
2. I just need to get **physical memory** of HPUXPARISC system in some way that is with or without a regex i need to get **6289408** value out of below output

   ```
   May  4 21:07:00 getz vmunix:     Physical: 6289408 Kbytes, lockable: 4604660 Kbytes, available: 5417880 Kbytes
   ```

which is my output to find out **physical memory** using command `grep "Physical" /var/adm/syslog/syslog.log`

Comment: How come I answered first with the correct neat one-line solution, but another guy who has a worse code (way more code without any more value) answer gets the tick and votes???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '{print $7}' input
6289408
```

cut

```
cut -d" " -f7 input
```

perl

```
perl -lane 'print $F[6]'
```

In your update, you added java; here's an working example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SimpleRegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sampleText = " May  4 21:07:00 getz vmunix:     Physical: 6289408 Kbytes, lockable: 4604660 Kbytes, available: 5417880 Kbytes";
        String sampleRegex = "Physical: (\\d+)";
        java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(sampleRegex);
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(sampleText);

        if (m.find()) {
            String matchedText = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(matchedText);
        } else {
            System.out.println("didn't match");
        }
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
$ java SimpleRegexTest
6289408
```

Comment: @Fredrik: How can i use lookahead to ignore till `Physical:`? then may be i can get it :)

Comment: @Fredrik: Thanks for the java code.. but i already have my java code in place. I am just writing plugins in which i just need to provide the regex and it will give me back the result. So i was hoping to get a `regex` that gets me `Physical:` 's value

Comment: See line 7 and line 11 above; or am I completely missing out on your question? regexp is `Physical: (\\d+)"` and you extract the value using `m.group(1)`

Comment: @Fredrik: no java code is needed. goto [http://gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) here you can paste my output and get back the `Physical:`'s value. i.e., i only want a regex

Comment: http://regexr.com?2u3rj i.e get first numerical value greater than 2 consecutive digits

Comment: @Fredrik: Thanks, can you also give a brief explanation what it does?

Comment: it matches the first occurrence of consecutive digits that are three or more. 3 was chosen as to be greater than 2 as in the timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Capture group 1 of `Physical: (\d+)`

Here's the java solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = " May  4 21:07:00 getz vmunix:     Physical: 6289408 Kbytes, lockable: 4604660 Kbytes, available: 5417880 Kbytes";
    String regex = "^.*Physical: (\\d*) .*$"; // <-- LOOK HERE FOR REGEX!
    String physical = input.replaceAll(regex, "$1"); // <-- How to extract group 1 in java
    System.out.println(physical); // "6289408"
}
```

If you need to capture the units too, use this:

```
    String physical = input.replaceAll("^.*Physical: (\\d*) (\\w*).*$", "$1 $2"); // "6289408 Kbytes"
```

Comment: @Bohemian: I just need the regex, i have java code which parses the regex and displays the result. Check my updated qn. just help me get the regex for it :)

Comment: Thanks for the java code.. but i already have my java code in place. I am just writing plugins in which i just need to provide the regex and it will give me back the result. So i was hoping to get a `regex` that gets me `Physical:` 's value

Comment: Did you actually READ my answer - it has the regex in there!

Comment: @Bohemian: take a look [here](http://regexr.com?2u430) i tried your regex, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Abhishek-Simon It absolutely DOES work. The problem is you haven't realised that in java Strings you must escape the escapes - ie `\` is written `\\`. Here's the native regex: `"^.*Physical: (\d*) .*$"`. btw, I am certain it works because I tested it in java before pasting it in here.

Comment: @Bohemian: I am sure your java code is giving the required result, but as i said before, i just need the regex to be given as a parameter to my java code, (so no java code was needed only `regex`) as for the regex, check [here](http://regexr.com?2u439) it selects the whole string. I only wanted `6289408` to highlight. Sorry for so much of confusion. Thanks for answering. +1 for your java code :)

Comment: @Abhishek-Simon notice I'm capturing group `$1` (and optionally `$2`), not the whole regex. For a neat regex that captures *just* the size, use this: `(?<Physical: )\d*`

Comment: @Bohemian: you mean `(?<=Physical: )\d*` [link](http://regexr.com?2u46l) I made a slight change. Thanks, i already marked Frederik so i can just give you a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

(Physical\:\s\d{0,10})
This better than \d+